# Groupby aggregation in pandas and specific condition

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as shown below

```
Sector      Plot       Usage        Status
SE1         1          Garden       Constructed
SE1         2          School       Constructed
SE1         3          Garden       Not_Constructed
SE1         4          School       Constructed
SE1         5          Garden       Not_Constructed
SE1         6          School       Not_Constructed
SE2         1          School       Constructed
SE2         2          School       Constructed
SE2         3          Garden       Constructed
SE2         4          School       Constructed
SE2         5          School       Not_Constructed
SE2         6          School       Not_Constructed
```

From the above I would like prepare below dataframe

Expected Output:

```
Sector  N_of_Garden_Const  N_of_School_Const   N_of_Garden_Not_Const  N_of_School_Not_Const 
SE1     1                  2                   2                      1 
SE2     1                  3                   0                      2
```

Where
 N_of_Garden_Const = Number of Garden constructed

N_of_School_Const = Number of School constructed

N_of_Garden_Not_Const = Number of Garden not constructed

N_of_School_Not_Const = Number of School not constructed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with flatten `MultiIndex in columns` by `map`:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['Sector'], [df['Status'], df['Usage']])
df.columns = df.columns.map('N_of_{0[1]}_{0[0]}_Const'.format)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)

  Sector  N_of_Garden_Constructed_Const  N_of_School_Constructed_Const  \
0    SE1                              1                              2   
1    SE2                              1                              3   

   N_of_Garden_Not_Constructed_Const  N_of_School_Not_Constructed_Const  
0                                  2                                  1  
1                                  0                                  2
```

Another idea with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) and flatten by `f-string`s:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='Sector', 
                    columns=['Status','Usage'], 
                    aggfunc='size', 
                    fill_value=0)
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'N_of_{x[1]}_{x[0]}_Const')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  Sector  N_of_Garden_Constructed_Const  N_of_School_Constructed_Const  \
0    SE1                              1                              2   
1    SE2                              1                              3   

   N_of_Garden_Not_Constructed_Const  N_of_School_Not_Constructed_Const  
0                                  2                                  1  
1                                  0                                  2
```

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method with [UNSTACKING](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) of columns. Check the code below:

```
dfGrouped = df.groupby(['Sector', 'Usage', 'Status'])['Plot'].count().unstack([-2, -1])
dfGrouped.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in dfGrouped.columns.values]
dfGrouped.fillna(0, inplace = True)
```

Output :

```
        Garden Constructed  Garden Not_Constructed  School Constructed  School Not_Constructed
Sector
SE1                    1.0                     2.0                 2.0                     1.0
SE2                    1.0                     0.0                 3.0                     2.0
```